# How can i get data from web service using android

Tags: android

Hi, I am new to android. I want to get data from webservice. in which key's are store in an array . and ley values stores in another array. In webservice data are display like,

`{"1":{"para_id":"1","para_parent_id":"0","para_level":"0","para_type":"0","para_value":"Salution","para_desc":"Salution","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Salution","created_dt":"2011-08-11 19:47:05","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-11 19:47:05","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"1001":{"para_id":"1001","para_parent_id":"1","para_level":"0","para_type":"1","para_value":"Mr.","para_desc":"Mr.","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Mr.","created_dt":"2011-08-11 19:47:21","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-11 19:47:21","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"1002":{"para_id":"1002","para_parent_id":"1","para_level":"0","para_type":"1","para_value":"Ms.","para_desc":"Ms.","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Ms.","created_dt":"2011-08-11 19:49:00","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-11 19:49:00","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"1003":{"para_id":"1003","para_parent_id":"1","para_level":"0","para_type":"1","para_value":"Mrs.","para_desc":"Mrs.","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Mrs.","created_dt":"2011-08-12 09:40:14","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-12 09:40:14","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"2":{"para_id":"2","para_parent_id":"0","para_level":"0","para_type":"0","para_value":"Appointment Types","para_desc":"Appointment Types","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Appointment Types","created_dt":"2011-08-16 15:43:15","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-16 15:43:15","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"2001":{"para_id":"2001","para_parent_id":"2","para_level":"0","para_type":"2","para_value":"Scheduled","para_desc":"Scheduled","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Scheduled","created_dt":"2011-08-16 15:43:36","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-16 15:43:36","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"2002":{"para_id":"2002","para_parent_id":"2","para_level":"0","para_type":"2","para_value":"Cancelled","para_desc":"Cancelled","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Cancelled","created_dt":"2011-08-16 15:43:51","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-16 15:43:51","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"2003":{"para_id":"2003","para_parent_id":"2","para_level":"0","para_type":"2","para_value":"Re-Scheduled","para_desc":"Re-Scheduled","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Re-Scheduled","created_dt":"2011-08-16 15:44:24","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-16 15:44:24","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"2004":{"para_id":"2004","para_parent_id":"2","para_level":"0","para_type":"2","para_value":"Deleted","para_desc":"Deleted","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Deleted","created_dt":"2011-08-16 15:44:38","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-16 15:44:38","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"3":{"para_id":"3","para_parent_id":"0","para_level":"0","para_type":"0","para_value":"Customer Status","para_desc":"Customer Status","para_sort_order":"1","para_tech_desc":"Customer Status","created_dt":"2011-08-29 12:51:48","created_by":"1","updated_dt":"2011-08-29 12:51:48","updated_by":"1","status":"A"},"3001":`

I want to sore key "1" ,"2", "3" in an array  and related value in another array.and get the data. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this looks like [JSON](http://www.json.org/), so use a JSON-Parser, for a tutorial see [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-andbene1/index.html?ca=drs-). You can make your JSON more readable (especially when asking on SO) using the [JSON beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: yes, this is json parser. but wan't code for add main key values like, "1","2","3"...in an array and it's related value to another array.